# right way to get the correct element from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, algorithm

I have the following two arrays:

```
var nodes = new Array();
var arr = [{
        name:"abc1",
        type:"blue"
    }, {
        name:"abc2",
        type:"red"
    }, {
        name:"abc3",
        type:"red"
    }, {
        name:"abc4",
        type:"green"
    }, {
        name:"abc5",
        type:"red"
    }, {
        name:"abc6",
        type:"blue"
    }];
```

Reading the info from "**arr**" I have got a table with **2** rows where no info on the elements with type not "**blue**" is given:

```
 ---------------------
 |    | name | type  |  } - thead
 ---------------------
 | [] | abc1 | blue  |  } - 1st row
 ---------------------   
 | [] | abc6 | blue  |  } - 2nd row
 ---------------------
```

The checkbox element of each row has a class "**table_row_checkboxes**"

Clicking on a checkbox in a row I find the index of the whole row.
Than I test if the checkbox checked or not.
If it is, than fill the new array called "**nodes**" with the names.
If it is not, than empty the array.

```
$(".table_row_checkboxes").click(function(){
    var idx = $(this).closest("tr").index(); // row index of the table

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        nodes.push(arr[idx].name);
    } else if($(this).not(":checked")) {
        nodes = $.grep(nodes, function(val_name) {
            return val_name != arr[idx].name;
        });
    }
}
```

Now my problem is, when I click on the element of the table with name "**abc6**" I get the index number "**1**" of the element, which corresponds to the element "**abc2**" in "**arr**", and my new array "**nodes**" is filled with name "**abc2**" instead of "**abc6**".

My question is, can someone give me a hint, which gets it right?

Comment: when things go wrong, add a fiddle also if possible.

Comment: You've got a missing quote in the first object. I assume that's just the way it's pasted and not in your code...

Comment: Yes, it is correct in my code.I change it here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have a connection between your array and the created table.

I would suggest to set a custom attribute to the table row (tr) ([Custom Data Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)) and read this on click.

Your table row html should look like:

```
<tr data-array-index="5">[...]</tr>
```

Now you can retrieve the array index of the row via:

```
$(".table_row_checkboxes").click(function(){
    var arrayIndex = $(this).closest("tr").attr("data-array-index");
    [...]
```

I did not test it. But I think the approach is right.

Comment: Amazing! What a miracle! Thanks a lot, wow! It worked fine! You made my day!